# Django auth and import auth.User

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, model

Hi i follow djangogirls tutorial for learning django

in the tutorial they use

> author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

But they import nothing for `auth.User` Why?
i see in many tutorials this code:

> from django.contrib.auth.models import User

whats diffrent beetween calling without import and calling with import

Thanks.

Comment: There is no semantical difference. But importing things can result in trouble: if you have *circular imports*, then Python can not run the program. It is thus often used to fix circular imports. Furthermore both are usually not a good idea, since one can use another `User` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So the good way is calling without import?

Comment: Yes, in model definitions only. It won't work in other code.

Comment: Not per se, both have advantages. The main advantage of using imports is that IDEs understand this better, and thus in case one renames a model, then it is renamed in the reference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its used to avoid running into a circular import situation,

But even better is using `get_user_model()` see here in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)